# how to get user input values and post them with axios

Tags: javascript

I've built a contact form and I'm trying to get my user inputted values to post using axios so I then get an email with the data inputted by the user.

I keep getting undefined values in my emails being sent. My server side is fine, I'm not to worried about that. What's the best approach for this?

```js
document.querySelector(".contact-btn").addEventListener("click", sendIt);

function sendIt(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios
        .post("https://us-central1-selexin-website.cloudfunctions.net/app/sendemail", {
            name: "",
            email: "",
            number: "",
            message: "",
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might work, also you can re-read documentation on `POST` Request [Axios Documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios)

For Live view how it works you can check on **[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/callmenikk/pen/NWgxozj?editors=1111)**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const input = document.querySelector("input")


const submitUser = () => {
  axios.post('https://us-central1-selexin-website.cloudfunctions.net/app/sendemail', {
    firstName: input.value,
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  submitUser()
  e.preventDefault()
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks callmenkikk. Appreciate your help.